# Load XML file as asset in iPhone - objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

Is there a way to open an XML file as a mail attachment or web download and load it into an iPhone app?

I want my app to be able to open a XML file as a mail attachment and then parse. I know how to do the parsing, but I don't know how to load the XML file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look into [Document Interaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403) you can [register your app to receive files of certain types](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1), yours being .xml.

[Opening Supported File Types](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010412-SW1)